# Lie algebra of a semi-direct product of Lie groups

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, group-homomorphism, semidirect-product

Let $G$ and $H$ be Lie groups with Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{h}$ and suppose $G$ acts on $H$ by automorphisms, i.e. there exists a Lie group homomorphism $\phi:G\to Aut(H)$. Consider the semidirect product $G\ltimes H$, which is again a Lie Group. Is its Lie algebra the semidirect product Lie algebra of $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{h}$?

Comment: Yes, that’s right.

Comment: How do I see it? Sure, $\phi$ induces a Lie algebra homomorphism $\mathfrak{g}\to Lie(Aut(H))$, but what can I say about the latter?

Comment: I posted the answer to this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3378416/describing-the-lie-algebra-structure-of-a-semi-direct-product-of-lie-groups). Is it just coincidence two users ask such a similar question a few hours apart?

Comment: Voted as duplicate of [Describing the Lie algebra structure of a semi-direct product of Lie groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3378416/describing-the-lie-algebra-structure-of-a-semi-direct-product-of-lie-groups) by presumably the same OP under another account.