# Computing Lie algebra of semidirect product

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, semidirect-product

I have the following problem.

> Given the following homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow$Aut($\mathbb{R}^2$), $\phi(t)$=
>   $\left(\begin{matrix}
> e^{kt} & 0\\
> 0&e^{-kt}\\
> \end{matrix}\right)$, where $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $e^{kt}+e^{-kt}\neq2$.
>   Then, what is the Lie  algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of $\mathbb{R}\rtimes_\phi\mathbb{R}^2$?

According to "Symplectic Manifolds with no Kähler structures" from Tralle and Oprea, then the solution is $\mathfrak{g}=<X,Y,Z;[X,Y]=kY,[X,Z]=-kZ,[Y,Z]=0, k\in\mathbb{R}>$

I am however clueless as to how this is achieved

Note: To my understanding the product on $\mathbb{R}\rtimes_\phi\mathbb{R}^2$ is $(x,(y,z))\cdot(x',(y',z'))=(x+x',(y+y'e^{kt},z+z'e^{-kt}))$ and $X =(1,0,0),Y=(0,1,0),Z=(0,0,1)$.
However if this were correct then $[X,Y]=(e^{k}-1)Y$ which does not agree with the afore mentioned book.
Thanks to anyone who is willing to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using the group product to calculate the commutator - you should actually be using the linearisation of it ($X, Y$ are elements of the Lie algebra, not the Lie group). A general derivation of the Lie algebra of the semidirect product is posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3378416/describing-the-lie-algebra-structure-of-a-semi-direct-product-of-lie-groups/3378604#3378604). In the notation there,
$$
[(X,0),(0,Y)] = (0,X\cdot Y) = (0,kY),
$$
and similarly for other brackets.

Comment: You're right! Thanks for the link!